# Java - netbeans - Undo / Redo Code for a notepadGUI

Tags: java, undo, notepad, redo

I’m making a notepad app as a Beginner project on NetBeans, in the edit menu, I’m looking To code a Undo Button and also a Redo Button for the last actions performed?  For example, if I want to undo a paste or Cut and be able to jump back a few actions to a previous state

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing Undo and Redo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undo) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

For this there are a few possible ways of tackling the problem.

One way, possibly the way I would do it, is store the contents of the notepad after every space key. This would allow you to press the undo button and set the text to the text before the last word was entered. For redo you could save the contents when backspace is pressed and restore it that way.

To implement this I would use an array list which is appended to with the current contents of the notepad (as a String), whenever space is pressed and/or whenever backspace is pressed and use the undo and redo buttons to cycle through the ArrayList.

I can't really give a much more detailed response as I don't know the entirety of your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , it took a few different methods but I got it sorted in the end